# Is it possible to use quiver() in matplotlib with color as function of the data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

Let us say that I am plotting a vector field with `quiver()` in matplotlib. I want the color of the arrows to reflect their magnitude, rather than their length.
Is it possible or should I use a workaround, maybe with `streamplot()`?

Comment: Did you try using the `C` argument described in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver)?

Comment: Also see the fourth example in the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html). The array M passed in as the fifth argument defines the varying colors.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I have to pay attention while rtfm. Now I have [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280498/change-color-limits-with-quiver-in-matplotlib) related to that, because I cannot control the `clim` keyword argument.